# Python to print previous line if an condition met in current line

Tags: python, arrays

`I creating health check script for the check the oracle data-gaurd status

The datagaurd status output will be like

```
<Database_Name 1> - Primary database
   Warning: ORA-16817: unsynchronized fast-start failover configuration
 <Database_Name 2> - (*) Physical standby database
   Warning: ORA-16817: unsynchronized fast-start failover configuration
```

or it will also like

```
<Database_Name 1> - Primary database
   Warning: ORA-16817: unsynchronized fast-start failover configuration
 <Database_Name 2> - (*) Physical standby database
   Warning: ORA-16817: unsynchronized fast-start failover configuration
```

so my requirement is to print the previous line when error "ORA" occurs means which database is having the ORA- Error

The output is small I can keep all the lines is buffer but the no:of lines is not constant. So is there any procedure to get the line number where ORA will be there and so print the previous line
This is the code I have tried

```
#!/usr/bin/env python import sys, os, time, threading, subprocess,datetime,re command = 'su - emadba -c \'dgmgrl -silent sys/password@emadb "show configuration"\'' dgstatus = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True) output = dgstatus.communicate()[0].strip().split("\n") prev = "" print prev for x in output: prev = x
```

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, os, time, threading, subprocess,datetime,re

command = 'su - emadba -c \'dgmgrl -silent sys/password@emadb "show configuration"\''
dgstatus = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
output = dgstatus.communicate()[0].strip().split("\n")
prev = ""
print prev
for x in output:
        prev = x
` 
This is what I have tried earlier

Comment: Please update your post with the code - comments are not meant to post code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating over the lines, can't you just keep the previous line in each iteration?

```
# Holds the previous line
prev_line = None
for line in open(<something>, 'r'):
    if is_ora_line(line) and prev_line is not None:
        do_something_with_database_line(prev_line)
    # Remember now the current line as the previous line
    prev_line = line
```

Comment: I used below code to get the output , Thanks
`
 command = 'su - emadba -c \'dgmgrl -silent sys/password@emadb "show configuration"\''
dgstatus = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
output = dgstatus.communicate()[0].strip().split("\n")
prev = None
for x in output:
        if re.search("ORA",x) or re.search("db",x) and prev is not None:
                print prev
        prev = x
`

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the error as a string, you can use `string.count("\n")` to get the count of newline characters. You can also use `string.split("\n")` which returns an array of lines of your string. `array[-1]` is the last line in the array, and `array[-2]` is the pre-last one.